# getSession of Openmeeting API is not working

Tags: rest, soap, openmeetings

hello I have create my web page and i create web service in it. i want to use getSession and loginuser method of Openmeeting SOAP. When I am using

http://[host]:[port]/openmeetings/services/UserService/getSession

from tutorial
http://www.zyxware.com/articles/5602/how-to-create-a-new-conference-using-soap-api-in-the-openmeeting

I am getting below response in browser.

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <soap:Body>
       <soap:Fault>
       <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
          <faultstring>
          No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params    unknown.
        </faultstring>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Even when I am using java client I am not able to find out getSession() method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

API has been changed in latest OpenMeetings

please check this REST example: http://openmeetings.apache.org/RestAPISample.html

SOAP will require similar calls

Comment: it is not a proper document

Comment: This is the ONLY proper document.